# Android R.Raw files in SD card?

Tags: java, android

The files we store in android R.raw folder(eg mySong.mp3) are present on Mobile internal memory or in SD card.

i have a song audio 100MB and i am using this in my android application.

```
      MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.mysong);
      mPlayer.start();
```

Just wanted to know that when user install .apk this 100MB song will stored in SD card or internal memory of phone ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well you can decide.

You can set the field **android:installLocation** in the root manifest element to prefer install location. values may be :

**internalOnly:** force internal

**preferExternal:** prefere SDCARD

**auto:**  System will decide

Install in sd card is supported only devices with android 2.2 and higher.

Comment: What is good approch for the case i have described above....for application size near 300MB what would you prefer auto or preferExternal

Answer (score 0):

Depend on your apps store.you install apps in SDcard so R.Raw store in Sdcard otherwise phonememory.

one solution of your question.when you install apps then after go to application->manage->click on apps and click on move to sdcard option.try this

Comment: Is there any way(code) that i can force application to store this MP3 files in Sd card memory ?

Comment: any link example/sample then it will great

Comment: <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>
   <manifest android:installLocation="preferExternal">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
   </manifest>
</android>

Comment: if you want store internal then write android:installLocation="internalOnly"

Comment: What is good approch for the case i have described above....for application size near 300MB what would you prefer auto or preferExternal